# Updating two or more tables in access

Tags: ms-access, updates, insert-update, subform

I have two tables which both include a Yes/No type column.  I wish to update both these columns using one form.

I do not want to use a subform design because I only want a few fields to show up in the form, not all fields from both tables.

Comment: If you use a query based on the table as the subform record source, it can display just those fields listed in the query's `SELECT` clause ... whatever subset of the table's fields you choose.

Comment: Hey and thank you for that solution.  I tried that method but when I run the query Im told that the recordset cannot be updated, whatam i doing wrong?

Comment: You will need an updateable query.  Open the query independently from the form ... can you edit query values in Datasheet View?  If not, show us the query's SQL (switch to SQL View in the query designer).

Comment: No I cannot update in Datasheet view either.   SQL code:  SELECT BookingsT.BookingNumber, BookingsT.DateBooked, CustomersT.Title, CustomersT.LastName, CustomersT.Postcode, RoomTypesT.RoomName, BookingsT.Nights, BookingsT.Price, BookingsT.Total, RoomTypesT.Occupied, BookingsT.CheckInDate, BookingsT.CheckedOutDate, CustomersT.CardNumber, CustomersT.ExpDate, CustomersT.SecurityCode
FROM CustomersT INNER JOIN (RoomTypesT INNER JOIN BookingsT ON (RoomTypesT.RoomID = BookingsT.Room) AND (RoomTypesT.RoomID = BookingsT.Room)) ON (CustomersT.CustomerID = BookingsT.CustomerID)

Comment: AND (CustomersT.CustomerID = BookingsT.CustomerID)
WHERE (((BookingsT.CheckInDate) Is Null) AND ((BookingsT.CheckedOutDate) Is Null));

Comment: Now I'm thoroughly confused.  I thought you were opposed to a subform because it would require you display all the fields from the table in that subform.  So I suggested a query based on that table where you `SELECT` only those fields you want, and use that query as the subform record source.  Your query sample joins 3 tables.  That is not what I suggested.  Are you using that SQL as the record source of a subform or the main/parent/top-level form?

Comment: oh I understand now. so basically from the 3 table make 3 separate queries only including the fields i want and then put all the queries into a form?

Comment: Have you ever designed Access forms with subforms?  I'm getting the impression this is not familiar territory for you.  I don't intend that question to insult you.  But if you don't understand subform basics, you have to either learn or figure out something else to do what you want.

Comment: yes it is unfamiliar territory, if it wasnt obvious enough thanks for making it clear ;)
so I cannot make seperate 3 queries and put them into one form (and will fields be able to be updated?)

Comment: No 3 queries in one form is not possible because a form can have only one record source.

Comment: thank you, are you able to suggest a method i can research to accomplish my desired result?

Comment: Even though you're not familiar with subforms, I think you should at least try that approach.  The answer I submitted can get you started quickly.  It should not cost you much time to decide whether it's worthwhile to pursue further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a description of a form/subform approach which you may be able to build on.

Save this query as *qryCustomers*:

```sql
SELECT
    cust.CustomerID,
    cust.Title,
    cust.LastName,
    cust.Postcode,
    cust.CardNumber,
    cust.ExpDate,
    cust.SecurityCode
FROM CustomersT AS cust;
```

Save this query as *qryBookings*:

```sql
SELECT
    bk.BookingNumber,
    bk.CustomerID,
    bk.DateBooked,
    bk.Nights,
    bk.Price,
    bk.Total,
    bk.CheckInDate,
    bk.CheckedOutDate
FROM BookingsT AS bk;
```

Create a new form which uses *qryBookings* as its records source.  Choose "Continuous Forms" as the Default View property from the Format tab of the form's property sheet.  After you add and arrange the data fields as you wish, save the form with the name *fsubBookings*.

Create another form which uses *qryCustomers* as its record source.  Choose "Single Form" as the form's Default View property.  Lay out your form's fields then add a subform control.  Assign *fsubBookings* as the "Source Object" property (find that property on the Data tab of the subcontrol's property sheet).  Use `CustomerID` for both the "Link Master Fields" and "Link Child Fields" properties.

Cross your fingers and switch the main form from Design to Form View.  Hopefully you will see information for one customer in the main form and any bookings for that customer displayed in the subform.  You can add new bookings for that customer in the subform.

If this suggestion proves to be a reasonable starting point, you can later adapt it to include what you need from `RoomTypesT`.  But for now, I tried to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: This was only intended as a very simple basic example.  You will want to refine it if it's worth anything at all to you.  And there is plenty of room for refinement.

Comment: thank you very much. getting it to do exactly what i want it to do. Thanks again HansUP. you helped me alot.the very simple example allowedme to elaborate where needed.  cheers. #hi five